# Unexpected end of query at HTML start?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, syntax-error, xquery

I am performing a query that works without HTML, but when I add HTML, to better organize the results.  When I add in `<div>` and `</div>` tags, I get an error (see below).  Here's the query:

```
let $doc := doc('test')  
for $v in $doc//item 
where $v/product_info/unit[.='9291']
return 
  <div>{ $v/seller_info/seller_company_id[position() lt 2]/text() } 
  </div> 
  <div>{ $v/seller_info/seller_rating[position() lt 3]/text() 
  </div>
```

On this document:

```
<item>
<item_number>1171270</item_number>
<seller_info>
<seller_company_id>6356</seller_company_id>
<seller_rating>C31</seller_rating>
<seller_rating>T150 hr.</seller_rating>
</seller_info>
<product_info>
<unit>2022</unit>
<sinfo>55 cases</sinfo>
<sinfo>Yu-gi-oh trading card pack</sinfo>
<sinfo>.45kg per unit</sinfo>
<sinfo>24.7500kg shipment</sinfo>
</product_info>
<product_info>
<unit>9291</unit>
<sinfo>7 units</sinfo>
<sinfo>Naruto, Classic, action figure</sinfo>
<sinfo>1.8kg per unit</sinfo>
<sinfo>12.6kg shipment</sinfo>
</product_info>
</item>
```

And the error I'm getting:

> Stopped at line 4, column 85: [XPST0003] Unexpected end of query: '>{ $v/seller_in...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to return multiple elements, you will have to wrap them in a sequence. Additionally, you forgot the closing `}` in the second `<div/>`.

```
let $doc := doc('test')  
for $v in $doc//item 
where $v/product_info/unit[.='9291']
return 
(
  <div>{ $v/seller_info/seller_company_id[position() lt 2]/text() } 
  </div>,
  <div>{ $v/seller_info/seller_rating[position() lt 3]/text() }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: So, basically the missed comma, right?  I'm also trying to iterate through the results....  Putting a <div> around each member of the sequence's every returned result.

Comment: You also missed the parentheses, which actually form the sequence. The comma is only for dividing the elements.